# Как подключить Navigation Controller на определенные экраны?

Tags: swift

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтоб navigation controller начинал работать только лишь с определенного экрана в приложении? Например у меня есть регистрация, пройдя которую попадаешь на главное меню, где и должен подключаться navigation controller. Но в до этого его не должно быть...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от того где вы создаете контролем на который переходите.

1. StoryBoard: Тут необходимо выделить скрин контроллера на который вы хотите перейти и выполнить **Editor->EmbedIn->NavigationController**
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Непосредственно в коде: Для этого после инициализации `UIViewController` необходимо создать `UINavigationController`. И назначить созданный `UIViewController` рутом `UINavigationController`

`let tempController = UIViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tempController)
//При переходе на новый котроллер, необходимо переходить на созданный NavigationController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigationController, animated: true)`

Comment: Если создаю Navigation Controller после окна с регистрацией, То переходов нет вообще. Вот накидал в сториборде точную копию, что я делаю не так? Если сделать сегвей на navigation controller, то на первом экране появляется кнопка назад (скрин 2), которая мне там совсем не нужна)

Comment: Просто прячьте navigation bar:  navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true в кажом контроллере. Либо создайте класс UINavigationController перепешите инит уже с navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true, и после пропишите этот клас в Storyboard.

Comment: Огромное спасибо